# How can format Android ListView for html?

Tags: android

With my ListView in Android Application made in Eclipse:

```
ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(xRemote));

listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow,
        R.id.rowTextView, planetList);          

listAdapter.addAll(xRemote);
mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Get this output:

```
https://www.LinkFromImageonTheGoogle.net/myImage.png
23/03/2014
<a href=http://www.mywebpage.net?ID=764>My remote pics</a>

https://www.LinkFromImageonTheGoogle.net/myImage1.png
22/03/2014
<a href=http://www.mywebpage.net?ID=765>My remote pics 1</a>

https://www.LinkFromImageonTheGoogle.net/myImage2.png
21/03/2014
<a href=http://www.mywebpage.net?ID=766>My remote pics 2</a>
```

How can I format this output in html?

Comment: i don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Have a look at `Html.fromHtml()` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

Comment: I need html output on ListView ...

Comment: `listAdapter.addAll(Html.fromHtml(xRemote.toString()));`  The method addAll(Collection<? extends String>) in the type ArrayAdapter<String> is not applicable for the arguments (Spanned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to create a custom `View` for each ListItem based on the HTML response (e.g., an `ImageView` positioned next to a Text`enter code here`View, with link behaviors, etc), but you could technically use a `WebView` for each ListItem, but that'd be pretty inefficient.

To provide a custom `View` (or `ViewGroup`), you provide your own implementation of an `Adapter` class, and override the appropriate methods.  For example, you might create a custom class that extends `BaseAdapter` (probably the most flexible option), and override the `getView` method to return the appropriate set of elements.  There are many tutorials and examples for custom `ListViews` with `Adapters` all over the net and the Android docs.